# Automatically trigger a workflow when a record is opened

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

Is there any way to automatically trigger a Custom Workflow Activity every time any Entity's record is opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you could use the `ExecuteWorkflow` request from some JavaScript that runs on Form Load. Here's an example of calling `ExecuteWorkflow` from JavaScript.

http://www.mscrmconsultant.com/2013/03/execute-workflow-using-javascript-in.html

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to trigger a custom workflow activity, and don't need to do anything workflow related in it, I'd recommend creating a custom action.  It is very similar to a workflow, but CRM will create a custom end point for you to call.  It eliminates the need to keep track of workflow IDs...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Plugin` instead of Custom Workflow, and register it on the "Retrieve" message.

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
// Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext context = (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext)
    serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext));

if (context.Depth == 1)
{
    IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
    IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

    // Obtain the target entity from the input parmameters.
    EntityReference entity = (EntityReference)context.InputParameters["Target"];

    ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet(
                         new String[] { "lastname", "firstname", "address1_name" });

    var contact = service.Retrieve("contact", entity.Id, cols);

    if (contact != null)
    {
        if (contact.Attributes.Contains("address1_name") == false)
        {
            Random rndgen = new Random();
            contact.Attributes.Add("address1_name", "first time value: " + rndgen.Next().ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            contact["address1_name"] = "i already exist";
        }
        service.Update(contact);
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

[CRM 2011–Retrieve Plugin](http://davecorun.com/blog/2012/01/05/crm-2011retrieve-plugin/)